# Why regex findall return a weird \x00

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I use a regex to build a list of all key-value pair present on line(string).
My key-pair syntax respect/match the following regex:

```
 re.compile("\((.*?),(.*?)\)")
```

typically I have to parse a string like:

```
(hex, 0x123456)
```

If I use the interpreter it's OK

```
str = "(hex,0x123456)"
>>> KeyPair = re.findall(MyRegex, str)
>>> KeyPair
[('hex', '0x123456')]
```

But when I use that code under linux to parse a command line output I get:

```
[('hex', '0x123456\x00')]
```

it comes from the following code

```
 KeyPayList = []
 # some code ....
 process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd_line, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
 # here we parse the output
 for line in process.stdout:
     if line.startswith(lineStartWith):
         KeyPair = re.findall(MyRegex, line.strip())
         KeyPayList.append(KeyPair)
```

Do you know why I get that strange `\x00` in the second group I captured ? 
Note that I already try to strip the string before calling `findall`.

Comment: Show how you're setting the string in the second case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a null byte, and it is present in your *original string*. You may not have seen it, as your terminal will ignore it when you print the string:

```
>>> s = "(hex,0x123456\x00)"
>>> print s
(hex,0x123456)
```

The Python `repr()` function used for container contents (such as the contents of the tuple you are printing here) *does* show it:

```
>>> print repr(s)
'(hex,0x123456\x00)'
```

Your regular expression is simply returning that null byte because it is present in your original string:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "(hex,0x123456\x00)"
>>> yourpattern = re.compile("\((.*?),(.*?)\)")
>>> yourpattern.search(s).groups()
('hex', '0x123456\x00')
```

If you were to remove it, the regular expression engine won't return it either:

```
>>> yourpattern.search(s.replace('\x00', '')).groups()
('hex', '0x123456')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simply that, in your case, the strings yielded by the `process.stdout` iterator contain null bytes.

Without a specific list of characters to remove, `strip` deletes *whitespace* characters. That means tab, linefeed, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space.

Many of those aren't relevant to most applications, but if you want to remove null characters then you must say so explicitly. For instance, if you wanted to remove tabs, spaces, and nulls, then you would write

```
line.strip('\x00\x09\x20')
```